# Google Maps: My Maps: Delete All

Tags: google-maps

I can delete maps I created in *My Maps* one at a time -- but I'd like to just delete all. Is there a way to do this (one at a time can be very slow during testing where you are making many many test maps).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage all of your maps via Google Drive. You have to permanently delete the map (empty the Trash) for it to be removed from My Maps.

[My Map's Help](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/6138031?hl=en&ref_topic=3024969#Delete)